# php file_exists does not work for array

Tags: php

I posted this question earlier but I have now used the feedback and simplified the php program to show how it still fails.
using the file_exists with an array always fails:
Here is a simple program I wrote that shows the failure:

```
[root@dsmpp1 steve]# ls -l data
 total 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 19 11:41 test_file 
[root@dsmpp1 steve]# cat test_file.php
`#!/usr/bin/php -q 
    <?php 
    $i=1; 
    $testarray=array(); 
    $testarray[$i]="test_file"; 
    echo "testarray $testarray[$i]\n";
     **if(file_exists("/home/steve/data/testarray[$i]")) {**
    echo "file exists\n"; } 
    else { echo "file does not exist\n"; } `    
[root@dsmpp1 steve]# php -q test_file.php 
testarray test_file 
file does not exist 
[root@dsmpp1 steve]#
```

I used the double quotes around the directory and file name as suggested earlier
and it is still not working.

Comment: Thank you everyone for commenting.  Here is a simple program anyone can try and you will get the same results I am getting.  Every /etc/hosts file has a "localhost" entry for ip 127.0.0.1.  Try populating an array grepping on the IP.   The file_exists will not work.  Then try hard coding it and see the results.  Why when I poplulate an array using a command that returns the same value does the file_exists not work.  Please try the following with and without the comment on each of the assignments.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
$i=1;
$hostname=array();
$hostname[$i]=`grep 127.0.0.1 /etc/hosts |awk '{print $3}'`;
#$hostname[$i]="localhost";
echo "hostname[$i] = $hostname[$i]\n";
        if(file_exists("/home/steve/data/$hostname[$i]"))  {
                    echo "do nothing appserver file exists\n";
        }
                else {
                        echo "No file exists create one\n";
                        $touch=`touch /home/steve/data/$hostname[$i]`;
                     }
?>

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
$testarray[$i]="test_file.php";
```

instead of:

```
$testarray[$i]="test_file";
```

Comment: no i am not testing for the php script file, I am testing for the file in /home/steve/data/test_file.

Comment: The op showed output of ls command showing that the file was named "test_file"

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if(file_exists("/home/steve/data/{$testarray[$i]}")) {**
```

You were missing the $ before testarray

You might also need to wrap this in brackets because you are using two variables. so use {$testarray[$i]}

Comment: Yes thank you and after adding the $ it did not make a difference.  For some reason it is how the array is getting populated.  When hard coding the name in the file exists it works fine.  As far as I can see the array value has to have something different when I populate it using the following $appserver[$i]=`grep $ip[2] /etc/hosts |awk '{print $2}'`;     If I assign the same name to appserver[$i] by actually assigning the value the file_exists works.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `$` before testarray in the if clause. try this:

```
if(file_exists("/home/steve/data/".$testarray[$i])) {
```

Comment: well, does the file actually exist? and what are the ** in front of the if?

Comment: what happens when you hard code the file name in the if condition?

Comment: First yes I realized I did not have the $ in front of the testarray.

Comment: However when I added the $ it still made no difference.  Hard coding the name does work.   I do not know why when I populate the array with $appserver[$i]=`grep $ip[2] /etc/hosts |awk '{print $2}'`;   it does not work.   Both hardcoding and the above code both yield the same name.

Comment: So I have determined it is not the double quotes, or a . before the variable or anything else.  It is how the array is being populated.